# Serializing a class containing List<Object>

Tags: c#, list, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am new to this site so I apologize for any improper formatting on my part.

I'm working on a project and am trying to Serialize a class that contains a List of type `TDF_Test` into an XML file but I keep getting the error "There was an error reflecting type `LoadInformation`".

I've read the Inner Exception as well and it says "There was an error reflecting property 'testList'". testList is the list of objects I'm trying to serialize.

Here is my class containing the List I want to serialize and save to an XML file.

```
namespace SPCTool.Core_Classes
{
    public class LoadInformation
    {
        public LoadInformation()
        { 
            testList = new List<TDF.TDF_Test>(); 
        }
        public List<TDF.TDF_Test> testList 
        { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is how I save it to the XML

```
LoadInformation info = new LoadInformation();
info.testList = someList; // someList is the same type as testList
SaveXML.SaveData(info, filename);
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
at SPCTool.User_Interfaces.MainForm.saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
M:\astburyj_TestProcess\IGXLTestProcess\TestProcess\tools\SPCReviewTool\SPCReviewTool\User Interface\MainForm.cs:line 940
```

Here is the class SaveXML

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace SPCTool.Core_Classes
{
    public class SaveXML
    {
        public static void SaveData(object obj, string filename)
        {
            XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
            sr.Serialize(writer, obj);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I've done a lot of searching and haven't found a good solution. Does anyone know what I can do? Let me know if you need any other information or code.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Show a stacktrace and include the code for `SaveXML.SaveData(info, filename);`

Comment: Something's missing in your question. There is no property `List` in this code. Also, are you using `XmlSerializer`? Can you post the code that creates the serializer?

Comment: Sorry Patrick, how do I get a stacktrace?

Comment: The stack trace is part of the exception object when things blow up.

Comment: You really need to add the code for the class/method SaveXML.SaveData so we can see how you are trying to serialize the xml.

Comment: Michael, the SaveXML.SaveData is all I'm doing to save the list. I guess it's not called serialization then?

Comment: If you object (TDF.TDF_Test) is not XML and List obviously is not XML then you probably should be using XmlSerializer instead of SaveXML.

Comment: Could you show me how to properly use the XMLSerializer with a List<>?

Comment: @astburyj You have yet to show us where you've attempted to serialize. If that's in SaveXML.SaveData, we need to see it.

Comment: SaveXML is up, sorry about that

Comment: @astburyj what is the inner exception?

Comment: @Yatrix There was an error reflecting property 'testList'

Comment: @astburyj Maybe try explicitly using an attribute. [XmlArrayItem("testList")] on your testList property

Comment: @Yatrix Tried that, but it didn't work

Comment: I believe the issue to be deeper into the Type `TDF_Test` which you have not shown us. I have been able to serialize the above code fine with a dummy `TDF_Test` class. But the serializer is complaining that its unable to reflect the property `TestList` because of issues with the Type the list contains. Consider going thorugh `TDF_Test` and annotating with `[Serializable]`, checking that all properties you need are serializable and everything not needed annotated with `[XmlIgnore]`. Further to that, show us more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XmlSerializer wants to write data according to a schema it can figure out in advance by inspection of the types. "Object" simply does not figure in this. It wants to know the *types*. The "good solution" here is simply: stop trying to serialize unknown / unpredictable data, and switch to a simple DTO model that your chosen serializer can reason about. In particular, standard into / string / float / etc members, nested sub-objects *where the type is advertised*, subclasses / inheritance *notified via XmlIncludeAttribute*, etc. Lists, arrays, collections are all fine too, obviously - but while SomeType[] is fine, Array or object[] are not.